# Retrieving error 417 at Post request

Tags: android, post, http-headers

I made an API, which I can send a Post request to, for a login. It works fine on Android 4.0, and I have another Android phone with 2.3, which works fine as well. 
Anyhow, When I test on a HTC Desire, I'm retrieving the 417 error from the API when I make a Post request. 
I already tried adding the USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE parameter to my HttpParams:

```
my_httpParams.setParameter(HttpProtocolParams.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
```

Also, I tried to add it to my Manifest like this:

```
<system.net>     
    <settings>         
        <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />     
    </settings> 
</system.net>
```

Is doesn't work though, and I have no idea why.. It's also weird that it does work on other devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The USE_EXPECTED_CONTINUE param needs to be set on the httpclient param, like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpParams params = httpclient.getParams(); 
params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE,false);
```

Works fine now!